# Track who changed a field in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to tell if a specific field in a database is updated by a specific username in mysql?

example:

DBNumber1 contains contactsTable. contactsTable contains firstName, lastName, phoneNumber.

UserA (db account) creates a record (id=102). Every field for that record was "last updated by" him on a date and time.
UserB updates that record (102). He changed an erroneous phoneNumber. firstName and lastName should be "last updated by UserA on date+time" and phoneNumber should be "last updated by UserB on different date+time."

What I have done so far has been add a column to the db that is last updated by, but I would like this to be for every field, not just the record. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a trigger that executes on update. Have it compare old and new values and take action, like inserting transactional data such as username and current time, row id etc in a separate "logging" table.

Comment: Would I create the trigger in mysql? or is it on the server?

Comment: It is a database trigger, created in mysql. It's basically a stored procedure that is invoked for a defined event. Google "mysql create trigger syntax"

Comment: Thank you. So I think I'll try something like this (psuedo code):
Trigger before insert (and a duplicate before update). output "SELECT USER(), the table I'm writting to, the fields I am updating, and the date and time."

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that Mysql is not aware of this. Bit what you can do is add a last_updated column for each column you want to keep record of. Or turn on binary logs (you'd need to check if the logs contain usernames, I guess they do) if you need non-automated logging. However, fetching data from there would be involve quite a lot of work (relatively) so this is only if you *think* you will need it very little.

Comment: I could write a perl parser to grab the info... finally learn some regex. Thanks, I'll look into this.